# How to send value to multiple constructors at object definition?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I have a simple program that determines the radius, area, and circumference of a circle. I want to have three constructors: the default constructor should sets the default values, the first overloaded constructor sets a value for radius, and the second overloaded constructor sets a value for the center of the circle.

However, at definition I would like to define a circle's radius AND its center by calling its constructors. When I try to do something like this:

```
Circles sphere(8);
Circles sphere(9,10);
```

I get a compiler error that makes sense:

> error: redefinition of 'sphere'

**So how can I define attributes using two different constructors at object definition?**

Here is my code (many functions left out as they are not relevant):

```
class Circles    
{
    public:
        Circles (float r);       // Constructor
        Circles();               // Default constructor
        Circles (int, int);              // Constructor for setting the center
    private: 
        float  radius;
        int    center_x;
        int    center_y;
};      

int main()
{
   Circles sphere(8);
   Circles sphere(9,10);

   //...
}

//Implementation section     Member function implementation

Circles::Circles()
{
   radius = 1;
   center_x = 0;
   center_y = 0;
}

Circles::Circles(float r)
{
   radius = r;
}

// Constructor for setting center 
Circles::Circles(int x, int y)
{
   center_x = x;
   center_y = y;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A constructor allows you to set an object's value on construction time.
It's meaningless to have it called again after it's constructed.

Either create a constructor that receives all the parameters you need.
Or, create an API to change the other parameters after construction.

Answer (score 1):

You could define four constructors:

```
Sphere::Sphere() : x(0), y(0), r(1) {}
Sphere::Sphere(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y), r(1) {}
Sphere::Sphere(double r) : x(0), y(0), r(r) {}
Sphere::Sphere(double x, double y, double r) : x(x), y(y), r(r) {}
```

but of course this doesn't scale.

C++ unfortunately doesn't provide support for named parameters and therefore the only other option is to first create the object and then set the attributes (directly or using setters).

You could try to emulate named parameters with something like:

```
Sphere s = Sphere::create()
             .center(10, 20)
             .radius(30)
             .color(255, 0, 0);
```

but this while scaling linearly on the number of parameters requires quite a bit of code:

```
struct Sphere {
    double x, y, r;
    unsigned color;

    Sphere(double x, double y, double r, unsigned color)
        : x(x), y(y), r(r), color(color)
    {
        printf("Building a sphere with "
               "center = (%0.3f, %0.3f) "
               "radius = %0.3f "
               "color = #%06x\n",
               x, y, r, color);
    }

    struct Builder {
        double x, y, r;
        unsigned col;
        Builder() : x(0), y(0), r(1), col(0x000000) {}
        operator Sphere () {
            return Sphere(x, y, r, col);
        }
        Builder& center(double x, double y) {
            this->x = x; this->y = y;
            return *this;
        }
        Builder& radius(double r) {
            this->r = r;
            return *this;
        }
        Builder& color(int r, int g, int b) {
            this->col = (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    static Builder create() { return Builder(); }
};
```

The code is very repetitive and when implementing a large system could make sense to generate builders automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've literally redefined `sphere`. Call the second variable something else.